# Twitter Feed (specific hastag) in iOS App

Tags: ios5, twitter

i would like to show a twitter feed of an specific hashtag in an UIViewController. best case only the images of this feed. is there any possibility to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

The [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) does not require authentication, so this is very easy to do.

The query you need to call is:

```
https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23iPhone&rpp=100&include_entities=true&result_type=recent
```

To explain:

```
q=%23iPhone
```

The # character of your hashtag has to be replaced with %23

```
rpp=100
```

Get 100 entries returned.

```
result_type=recent
```

Get the most recent tweets.

```
include_entities=true
```

This is the important one.  If you [include_entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities), you will get the images that people have uploaded to Twitter.

You can then parse the result to show the images in your app.

Comment: ok. thanks. but thats not Xcode. you mean to show this in an uiView to what?

Comment: No, that will get the JSON data from Twitter. You then parse that in xcode & extract whatever data you want to display.